# jQuery cloned table row not retrievable from DOM?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing some jquery to create a dynamic form table.

All it needs to do is clone a row, and then change a few properties of that row in order to make it unique.

So, my strategy is to first clone it, append it to the table, then get one of its child elements and modify it. Everything is working but the last part.

```
$(function () {
$(".appendRow").click(function() {
    var body = $(this).closest("tbody");
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var newNum = $(".operation").size();
    $("#test").append("<p>newNum: " + newNum + "</p>");
    var clone = row.clone();    
    body.append(clone);
    var newRow = $(".RowNumber").get(newNum);
    var newRowNum = newNum + 1;
    $("#test").append("<p>newRowNum: " + newRowNum + "</p>");
    // $("#test").append("<p>type: " + newRow.type() + "</p>"); // tried to check type with this, error
    //newRow.html(newRowNum); // trying to change html of span element, fails with error
}); 

});
```

The first commented line was meant to help me debug. It, and other other commented line, resulted in an error in Google Chrome:

Local exception, type error,  newRow is undefined.

Below is the html:

```
<form id="processname" name="processname" method="post" action="" >
<table border="1" width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle">Order</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle">Process</td>
<td>Operation</td>
<td>Value</td>
<td>+</td>
<td>&ndash;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="rowNumber">1</span></td>
<!--<td><span class="rowNumber">1</span></td>-->
<td>
<select class="process" name="category_1" id="category_1" onChange="javascript: dropdownlist(this); elementPos(this)">
<option value="">Select Category</option>

<option value="3" selected="selected">translate</option>
<option value="4">math</option>
<option value="5">format</option>
<option value="6">write</option></select></td>
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<select class="operation" name="operation_1" id="operation_1">
<option value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
<option value="s->c" selected="selected">Use source as core by default</option><option value="s->t->c">Only process translated values</option></select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="value_1" id="value_1" value="" />
</td>
    <td><input type="button" style="max-width:5em" class="appendRow" value="+" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="delRow" value="-" /></td>
</tr>
.
.
.

</table>
</form>
```

NOTE on May 29, 2013: I discovered recently that my Adblock Plus add on for Google Chrome was preventing class "addRow" from being visible (it uses `display:none` for a bunch of classes associated with ads). I've edited the question and answer to change the class to "appendRow" so that anyone copying this code won't have the same problem I just had.

Comment: Probably not related, but `$("#test")` doesn't select anything, since there's no `id="test"` in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that. There is a `<div id="test"></div>` that I used to show that the newRowNum and newNum variables were being set properly, which they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you append an element, then get that element from the DOM to modify it when you can modify it before you append it ?

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but maybe it's something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#processname').on('click', '.addRow', function() {
        var body = $(this).closest("tbody");
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var newNum = $(".operation").length + 1;
        var clone = row.clone();
        clone.find('.rowNumber').html(newNum);
        body.append(clone);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XeSbE/1/)

Comment: Your idea of what I'm trying to do is exactly correct, as is your answer. Why was I trying to do things in a strange way? Because this is approximately day1 for me with jquery so I don't know all the methods/shortcuts. Thank you!

Comment: @ButtleButkus - Updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XeSbE/2/) to remove rows as well, and if you need to change the id or value on an element inside the clone, you can just use regular jQuery methods on the clone to find and change stuff before you append the clone, as that would be faster and more efficient than changing the DOM severeal times etc.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. I was just trying to get the minus button to work myself. For some reason, my added rows' buttons don't work. Only the original rows. Perhaps it's because you are using the form id `#processname` as the "root selector" (or whatever you call it). I will change my code accordingly.

Comment: Also, perhaps you should change the Fiddle link in your answer because it still goes to your first version, rather than your updated version in your comment.

Comment: Yeah, the original fiddle answers the question so I'll keep that, and the other one is available in the comments anyway. And yes, the selector I'm using with `on()` is delegated so as to work with elements that are inserted dynamically like yours are.

Comment: It seems like this functionality has been broken in some jquery update. It stopped working on my site a couple of months ago.  I thought I had messed up some of the code myself, but now I see your fiddle isn't working anymore either. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Your fiddle has been broken by the jquery team. I have asked another question on the subject, if you think you can answer it. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806178/jquery-functionality-broken-in-new-version-dynamically-adding-rows-to-a-form-t

Comment: Never mind. It turns out the AdBlock addon for Chrome blocks class "addRow" with CSS `display:none`. All I had to do was change the class name to "appendRow" and it worked fine.